# gitlab-ci not working: runner cannot evaluate $ expression

Tags: bash, docker, ssh, gitlab

In the following `gitlab-ci.yml` file, I'm using the commit hash of my project as a tag for its docker container. Its supposed to do the following:

1. ssh on a server
2. save the hash of the current local commit to a file named `current`
3. pull and save the new hash to a file named `new`
4. get the hash from the existing backup docker container from its tag and save it to `old`
5. remove the old docker container
6. re-tag the last current as the new old one
7. create a new container with the newest hash from `new`

```yaml
# Setup SSH deploy keys
before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq
  - apt-get install -qq git
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

stages:
  - update
  - create

update_project:
  stage: update
  script:
    - ssh $SSH_CONNECTION "cd /$PROJECT_NAME && git rev-parse --short HEAD > current && git checkout $BRANCH && git reset --hard && git pull origin $BRANCH && git rev-parse --short HEAD > new && exit"

create_docker_container:
  stage: create
  script:
    - ssh $SSH_CONNECTION "cd /$PROJECT_NAME && docker images ${PROJECT_NAME}_old --format='{{ .Tag }}' > old && docker image rm ${PROJECT_NAME}_old:$(< old) && docker tag ${PROJECT_NAME}:$(< current) ${PROJECT_NAME}_old:$(< current) && docker image rm ${PROJECT_NAME}:$(< current) && docker build -t ${PROJECT_NAME}:$(< new) . && exit"
```

As you can see eg. in `${PROJECT_NAME}_old:$(< old)`, I'm using `$(< x)` to access the local files `new`, `current` and `old` throughout the yml file, which is not working as intended. My gitlab-ci is failing with:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.9.0 (4c96e5ad)
  on test abc123yz
Preparing the "docker" executor
Using Docker executor with image python:3.8.8-slim-buster ...
Pulling docker image python:3.8.8-slim-buster ...
Using docker image sha256:d97718c69437f6fcb5dd4588fc35ebfa2de7bfe536d0ce7d859d26f48e9ac840 for python:3.8.8-slim-buster ...
Preparing environment
Running on runner-yetZ9g1t-project-799-concurrent-0 via computer...
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/user/myproject/.git/
Checking out 123abc45 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Restoring cache
Downloading artifacts
Running before_script and script

...

$ ssh $SSH_CONNECTION "cd /$PROJECT_NAME && docker images ${PROJECT_NAME}_old --format='{{ .Tag }}' > old && docker image rm ${PROJECT_NAME}_old:$(< old) && docker tag ${PROJECT_NAME}:$(< current) ${PROJECT_NAME}_old:$(< current) && docker image rm ${PROJECT_NAME}:$(< current) && docker build -t ${PROJECT_NAME}:$(< new) . && exit"
/bin/bash: line 123: old: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: line 123: current: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: line 123: current: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: line 123: current: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: line 123: new: No such file or directory
Error response from daemon: invalid reference format
Running after_script
Uploading artifacts for failed job
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

It seems like my gitlab runner cannot evaluate `$(< x)`. If I try the exact same steps manually one by one, everything works fine. Am I doing something wrong? What else could I use here?

Comment: `$(< x)` opens the file and passes `/dev/fd/<fd of x>` as a parameter, which does not refer to the same file across `ssh`.

Comment: Note that this problem has nothing to do with Git itself (though it does have a lot to do with bash and ssh, as @mkayaalp noted, and of course gitlab for the yml).

Answer (score 0):

First, as show in this thread, I would double-check the rights of the ssh elements:

- `chmod 700` for `~/.ssh`
- `chmod 600` for `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

If would also make a simple:

```
ssh $SSH_CONNECTION "hostname;pwd;id -a;ls"
```

Just to check the SSH connection does work.

Regarding the command executed through SSH, I would prefer a script (to which you are passing a parameter), created/copied on the server, rather than a long and complex command which, as you see, involves issues being correctly interpreted by the shell.